# Подсветка svg элементов

Tags: css3, svg, javascript, css

Доброго времени суток.

У меня есть задача сделать подсветку svg элемента при наведении на него курсора мыши. Проблема заключается в том что кастомные стили элемента не должны изменяться. А подсветка должна появляться по бокам элемента.

Частично я уже понимаю что решить задачу можно с помощью svg фильтров. Только вот поверх элемента может быть расположен другой полупрозрачный элемент и подсветка первого будет частично затухать (если так можно выразиться).

Посоветуйте как быть.

Comment: svg елементы поддерживают css кастомизацию.

Comment: внешний вид элемента не должен изменяться

Comment: добавляешь какой-нибудь `<div id="svg-wrapper">` и контролируешь его стили. в чем проблема-то?

Comment: Не совсем понял? если svg элемент синий и цвет подсветки красный, то при наведении курсора мыши svg элемент должен остаться красным, и вокруг него должна появится подсветка синего цвета

Comment: Если элемент синий, то как он может остаться красным?
 
1.Как ты реализуешь эту самую подсветку?

2.Тебе нужна подсветка всего SVG-изображения 
(`<object>`,`<iframe>`,etc) или именно элемента SVG(`<circle>`, `<path>` etc). 

По-хорошенему нужен код иначе так и будет вангование.

Comment: смотрите ответ @dzhioev

Answer (score 3):

Это можно сделать с помощью css свойства filter и селектора :hover.
Вот пример http://jsfiddle.net/FvjA3/ .

```css
#rect:hover {
    filter: url("#glow-filter");
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="80">
    <filter id="glow-filter" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <feColorMatrix type="hueRotate" in="SourceGraphic" values="90" result="color" />
        <feGaussianBlur in="color" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
        <feMerge>
            <feMergeNode in="blur" />
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
        </feMerge>
    </filter>
    <rect id="rect" x="20" y="20" width="30" height="30" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Да это то о чем я говорил. Только вот проблема в том что элемент может быть перекрыт другим полупрозрачным элементом с pointer-events: visibleStroke и тогда при наведении на нижний элемент подсветка будет немного затухать. Но как вариант при mouseover поднимать элемент на самый верх, а при mouseout возвращать его на то место где он находился до этого